# How to store text as UTF-8 in GAE Text.Property field?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encoding, google-cloud-datastore

I know GAE is storing `db.TextProperty` by default as ASCII. How do I store utf-encoded text in a textField? I tried `db.Text(txt, encoding='utf_8')` but couldn't get it working.

Using the interactive console there is no traceback, just a plain `request failed`. But passing text without the 'Ü' for example works. So I'm sure it is an encoding issue. Can someone assist?

```
class Greeting(db.Model):
    lang_category = db.StringProperty(choices=("de_DE", "en_US", "pt_PT"), 
                                     required=True)
    greet_txt = db.TextProperty(required=True)


def put_greet(lang,txt):
    g = Greeting(lang_category = lang,
        greet_txt = db.Text(txt, encoding='utf_8'))
    g.put()


put_greet("de_DE","Voller Überzeugung.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
def put_greet(lang,txt):
    g = Greeting(lang_category = lang,
        greet_txt = db.Text(txt))
    g.put()
```

and

```
put_greet("de_DE", u"Voller Überzeugung.")
```

Also, I prefer to use the ndb (google.appengine.ext.ndb) module instead of the db.

Comment: Tried this before, also doesn't work in the interactive command. When running this via a script it does work though.

Comment: Indeed. It doesn't work in the development server, but the encoding error seems to come from the web interface, not the db module.